# Flutter send local notification when app is closed (alarm)

Tags: flutter

I am using flutter **awesome notification**.

Wish to send a notification when the app is **closed** (not running in background). Just like an Alarm Clock, the notification will be send at specific time. Not push from external services like firebase.

Is there a way for doing that? Or I need another package like **android_alarm_manager**?

Answer (score 1):

you can use [flutter_local_notification](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) and it has a feature called [scheduling-a-notification](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#scheduling-a-notification) and also you need to provide timezone with [timezone](https://pub.dev/packages/timezone) package to work that,

Import the timezone package

```
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;
```

Initialise the time zone database

```
tz.initializeTimeZones();
```

Once the time zone database has been initialised, developers may optionally want to set a default local location/time zone, you can use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_timezone to getting the local timezone of the os.

```
tz.setLocalLocation(tz.getLocation(timeZoneName));
```

Assuming the local location has been set, the zonedScheduled method can then be called in a manner similar to the following code

```
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
0,
'scheduled title',
'scheduled body',
tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local).add(const Duration(seconds: 5)),
const NotificationDetails(
    android: AndroidNotificationDetails('your channel id',
        'your channel name', 'your channel description')),
androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
    UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime);
```

Comment: as soon as I close the app I don't receive any notification

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with **schedule** parameter when creating notification

Example:

```
String localTimeZone =
    await AwesomeNotifications().getLocalTimeZoneIdentifier();

AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
  content: NotificationContent(
    payload: {},
    id: id,
    channelKey: 'scheduled',
    title: 'title',
    body: 'body',
  ),
  schedule: NotificationCalendar(
    day: day,
    month: month,
    year: year,
    second: second,
    millisecond: millisecond,
    timeZone: localTimeZone,
    repeats: false,
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If using Awesome_notifications on Android with flutter, use the schedule parameter as Sneh Mehta's reply but also make sure not to have your phone with battery saver mode and run the app in release mode with "flutter run --release"