# How do I show a notification when app is closed?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-notification

I saw different question regarding this topic like this one:
[Flutter send local notification when app is closed (alarm)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68478438/flutter-send-local-notification-when-app-is-closed-alarm)
Some of them with accepted answers but nothing seems to work with latest version. Notification package has changed and all of these examples are deprecated.

I tried actual version (`flutter_local_notifications: ^12.0.0`) and as soon as I close the app I don't receive any notification at all.

```
const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
  'high_importance_channel', // id
  'High Importance Notifications', // title
  importance: Importance.high,
);

var detroit = tz.getLocation('America/Detroit');
    var now = tz.TZDateTime.now(detroit);
    await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
      0,
      'scheduled title',
      'scheduled body',
      tz.TZDateTime.now(now.location).add(const Duration(seconds: 5)),
      NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          channel.id,
          channel.name,
        ),
      ),
      androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
      uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
          UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
    );
```

The only notifications that I implemented in the background are the ones coming from firebase cloud functions, but I don't want to rely on this for simple notifications (specially because of the plan).

Is there anything working out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was already working. The trick was to not test on debug:

```
flutter run --release
```